# How to stop earbuds from getting stuck in ears?

Tags: music

I have this issue where when I wear earbuds that sometimes one gets stuck in my ears. It's always easy to remove using tweezers but is there anyway I can overcome this problem completely?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an earbuds tip tip.

It happens that if the earbuds tips are too narrow, they will go too deeply into your ear canal. Everyone's ears are as different as you are genetically.

Mine went in so deeply on one side an otolaryngologist (ear doctor) had to use forceps to remove it. It was uncomfortable; so, I can commiserate with you.

The solution is to use larger earbud tips than the ones you used. This means considering both the shape of your inner ear and how deep or shallow your outer ear canal is. Pick ones that fit well and sound good.

Good luck.

Comment: *"...earbuds tip tip"*  I had to read that 2x to realize it was intentional. :)